# how to insert data to db in framework 7?

Tags: php, html-framework-7

i am looking for framework 7 data insert into database

using php database and i am using ajax to pass the data

**demo.js**

```
function save()
 {


                    var name = $$('.page').find('input[name="name"]').val();
                    var email = $$('.page').find('input[name="email"]').val();

            $.ajax({  
                 url:"insert.php",  
                 method:"POST",  
                 data:{name:name, email:email},  
                 dataType:"text",  
                 success:function(data)  
                 {  
                      alert("success") ;
                 }  
            });  
        }
```

**insert.php**

```
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "demo-app");

if(isset($_GET['add'])) 
{

$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['name']);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['email']);    


 echo   $sql ="INSERT INTO `register`(`name`, `email`) VALUES  
 ('".$name."','".$email."')";
$result = mysqli_query($connect,$sql)  ;    

if($result){
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Successfully Add.") 
</script>';
    echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=index.html'>";    
 }


}
```

anyone help me

thanks & regards,
Darshan

Comment: Probably you are in the right way, but: I think $.ajax is not a framework7 method. Is a Jquery method. No problem whith this. Then you are checking  a GET attributte in your php, but you are launching a POST request in the AJAX call. You can pass the GET atributte in the url : url:"insert.php?add=1"

Comment: When you launch  request via AJAX, you must return data in your php, not <script> actions. I recommend you to write JSON data in your php: i.e echo "{status:'ok'}". Then in your success function you can read this data:

success:function(data)  
                 { if (data.status=='ok') {alert('inserted');} }

Answer (score 0):

change your ajax call to

```
        $$.ajax({  
             url:"insert.php",  
             method:"POST",  
             data:{name:name, email:email},  
             dataType:"text",  
             success:function(data)  
             {  
                  alert("success") ;
             }  
        });
```

In F7 '$' dont work remember instead use $$

Answer (score 0):

> If you are working on Framework 7 Latest Version i.e. V-3... This gonna work for sure to hit your php api
>   Framework 7

`app.request.post("insert.php", {name:name, email:email}, function (data) {
     //And the response from api will come like this
     var data = JSON.parse(data); 
     if(data.status){
      app.dialog.alert("Success");
      }else{
       app.dialog.alert("Failed");
      }
});`

Php

```
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "demo-app");

if(isset($_POST['add'])) 
{

$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['name']);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['email']);    


$sql ="INSERT INTO `register`(`name`, `email`) VALUES  
                ('".$name."','".$email."')";
  $result = mysqli_query($connect,$sql)  ;    
  $return = array();
     if($result){
        $return['status'] = true;  
      }else{
         $return['status'] = false;  
      }
    echo json_encode($return);

}
```

//